# 'Foo.commit' ('void Function(Bar)') isn't a valid override of 'BaseFoo.commit' ('void Function(BaseBar)')

Tags: flutter, dart

I created a class `BaseBar` and a class `BaseFoo` . `BaseBar` has a method `commit` that takes `BaseBar` as parameter.

My goal is to extends  `BaseFoo` and override this method with a parameter that extends `BaseBar` but it doesn't work.

```
abstract class BaseBar {}

abstract class BaseFoo {
  void commit(BaseBar bar);
}

// implementaion
class Bar extends BaseBar {
  final String id;

  Bar(this.id);
}

class Foo extends BaseFoo {
  @override
  void commit(Bar bar) {}
}
```

Error is `'Foo.commit' ('void Function(Bar)') isn't a valid override of 'BaseFoo.commit' ('void Function(BaseBar)')`

Comment: Dart has a keyword called `covariant` that can help you. Look it up

Comment: Are you talking to yourself???